# B2 travel visa from Russia to the US

Tags: visas, usa, scams

A girl I met online says the travel agency she went to says she can't get a B2 visa to the US because she took a loan out to pay for her trip. Under Russian law she has to pay back a 680 US dollar loan to get the visa. She says the US embassy won't let her get an interview for the visa. Is this a scam? It sounds fishy to me. Can she get a visa and leave Russia?

Comment: Is this a scam? If you have to ask, the answer is obvious...

Comment: The US embassy won't give her an interview because of a Russian law concerning an outstanding debt?  That sounds very farfetched to me.

Comment: This IS a scam.

Answer (score 3):

**Do not continue speaking to this girl - she is a complete and utter fraud!**

US visas are issued in accordance with American, not Russian, law, which is why her issues with Russian authorities are out of scope for this procedure (unless of course it's a criminal record).

If she hasn't implied it yet, I can tell you she's looking for you to pay her these 680 dollars, after which she'll either keep asking for more for other made-up reasons, or disappear entirely.